# Monte Carlo to calculate Pi on multiple Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, montecarlo, pi

I wrote a simple Program in Java to calculate Pi via the Monte Carlo method. Since You need a lot of drops to get Pi 'precise' and it gets, of course, slower I decided to implement Multi-Threading. Now to my question: Is there any way to speed the calculation up? And calculates it only one iteration per physical thread at a time or am I completley wrong in my concept of multithreading?

Here is the code:

```
public class PiMC{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService exec=Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        //Future object is used to get result from a thread
        Future<Double> result0=exec.submit(new Thread1());
        Future<Double> result1=exec.submit(new Thread1());
        Future<Double> result2=exec.submit(new Thread1());
        Future<Double> result3=exec.submit(new Thread1());
        Future<Double> result4=exec.submit(new Thread1());
        Future<Double> result5=exec.submit(new Thread1());
        Future<Double> result6=exec.submit(new Thread1());
        Future<Double> result7=exec.submit(new Thread1());

        try
        {
            System.out.println(((result0.get() + result1.get() + result2.get() + result3.get() + result4.get()+ result5.get() + result6.get() + result7.get()) / Long.MAX_VALUE) * 4);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println(e);}
        catch(ExecutionException e){System.out.println(e);}
    }
}

class Thread1 implements Callable {
    @Override
    public Double call() throws Exception {
        long drops = Long.MAX_VALUE / 8;
        //long drops = 500;
        double in = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i <= drops; i++) {
            double x = Math.random();
            double y = Math.random();
            if (x * x + y * y <= 1) {
                in++;
            }
        }
        return in;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get the question. For starters the ExecutorService will default to a pool size of that of the number of logical processors - so if you only have 2 cores then it will only run two threads concurrently.  Multithreading will only run the code inside the call/run method once per thread.

Comment: One other possible reason why you don't see as much of a speed-up is that `Math.random()` uses the same `java.util.Random` instance internally, which leads to some resource contention. From the API doc of `Math.random()`: `However, if many threads need to generate pseudorandom numbers at a great rate, it may reduce contention for each thread to have its own pseudorandom-number generator.`

Comment: I extended it for a friend with 8 cores so he could calculate it faster, but he reportet he had 105% workload. I had a very high load too. Shouldn't the two random number generations and the calculation only need a little bit of capacity of the thread?
Ok, the problem with the API is probably a reason, is there any way to solve this?

Comment: @Acru If you want to keep the load small, why go with parallel computation? Multiple threads will of course max out CPU utilisation (if done well), that's what we're using parallel computation for.

Comment: It's easier if you imagine the CPU as a drainpipe with multiple inlets (these are the cores). And each thread is a bucket of water you want to pour into the drain. If you have 8 inlets and only 1 bucket, you'll only ever use 1/8th of the inlets, as you can't pour water from 1 bucket into two inlets at the same time. If you've got 8 inlets and 8 buckets, you utilise your drainpipe to the full. And if you've got 12 buckets, you'll always have 4 lining up on the floor, waiting to be emptied.

Comment: @biziclop I thought every thread would utilize one physical core so it would only put a small amount of load on every core of a 8-core processor.

Comment: @Acru You can't put a small load on a core. You either use it or you don't. It's like an LED light, it's on or it's off. You can simulate using it "only a little" by making it run the thread a bit, then stop and switch to something else, then run it again and so on. (Just like how you simulate dimming of LED lights) But there's nothing in your code that would tell Java to do that and ultimately you'll end up with a slower calculation anyway.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clearing that up. Would there be a solution to the Math.random() problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You realize how big Long.MAX_VALUE / 8 is? It is (2^63 - 1) / 8 which is about 1e18... quite a big number (even whith todays best computers filling whole buildings it takes at least 1000s, see comment).

The better approach would be to compare the previous calculated value with the current value for pi and compare them. If the difference is 0 (Happens because precision is limited --> eps is the smallest number > 0 where 1 + eps != 1) cancel execution and return the value:

```
int sum = 0, drops = 0;
double pi = 0, oldPi;
do {
     oldPi = pi;
     double x = Math.random(), y = Math.random();
     if (x * x + y * y <= 1)
         sum++;
     drops++;
     pi = 4.0 * sum / drops;
} while (pi != oldPi || pi < 3); // pi < 3 to avoid problems when the first
// drops are outside of the circle, pi == 0 would also work, BUT setting
// pi to a value different from 0 at the beginning can still fail with only pi != oldPi
```

If you want to use more than one thread it is difficult, because the update of the value for pi has to be synchronized you wouldn't gain much I guess. However several threads could calculate pi independently and you could compare (or average) the results.

Comment: Yeah but I hoped that the simplicity of the calculation would make the program fast enough to be solvable in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: I add the occurence of drops in the (imaginary) circle of every thread together and then calculate Pi out of it.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The best super computers are in the area of peta FLOP/s (floating point operations per second). So if you could be that fast for one drop it still would take 1000s (and one drop actually takes more than one operation). Also if you reached max precision there is no point in continuing (given the algorithm converges to some number).

Comment: Ok, seems like I underestimated the work to do and overestimated the workers, thank you.